# How to build autocomplete in textfield flutter

Tags: flutter

[image: Output View]

This is what I want to achieve.

```
Autocomplete(
    optionsBuilder: ((textEditingValue) {
      List<String> options = [
        "Hi",
        "Hello",
        "Hey",
        "How are you",
        "What's up",
      ];
      return options
          .where((option) => option
              .toLowerCase()
              .startsWith(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }),
    optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
      return const Material(
        child: SizedBox(),
      );
    },
    fieldViewBuilder:
        (context, textEditingController, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
      List<String> options = [
        "Hi",
        "Hello",
        "Hey",
        "How",
        "are",
        "you",
      ];
      final ValueNotifier<String> text = ValueNotifier<String>("");
      textEditingController.addListener(() {
        if (textEditingController.text != "") {
          String lastWord = textEditingController.text.split(' ').last;
          List<String> availableOptions = options
              .where(
                (option) => option.startsWith(lastWord),
              )
              .toList();
          if (availableOptions.isNotEmpty) {
            text.value = availableOptions.first;
          } else {
            text.value = "";
          }
        }
      });

      return Material(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
              valueListenable: text,
              builder: (context, String value, child) {
                String textValue = "";
                if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                  textValue = value;
                } else {
                  textValue = "";
                }
                return TextField(
                  enabled: false,
                  readOnly: true,
                  controller: TextEditingController(
                    text: textEditingController.text.replaceAll('*', " ") +
                        textValue.replaceAll('*', " "),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: textEditingController,
              onTap: () {
                List<String> words = textEditingController.text.split(' ');
                words.last = text.value;

                textEditingController.text = words.join(' ');
                textEditingController.selection =
                    TextSelection.fromPosition(
                  TextPosition(
                    offset: textEditingController.text.length,
                  ),
                );

                print("object");
              },
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
                if (value.contains('\t')) {
                  textEditingController.text = text.value;
                  textEditingController.selection =
                      TextSelection.fromPosition(
                    TextPosition(
                      offset: textEditingController.text.length,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

I have tried to use the Autocomplete widget to achieve this view. The below code works but have some issues can you guys try and make it perfect.
In this code optionsBuilder, optionViewBuilder is useless.
I have tried to use fieldViewBuilder and returning a stack of two TextField, one for suggestion and other for actual writing.
but the suggestion view overlaps with actual writing one.
We can achieve this without AutoComplete.

The problems is -
I am not able to move to cursor along with typing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an autocomplete with a list of object you can use this:
[Flutter TypeAhead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead)

And you can use a *card* or a *container* to decorate the widget.

I hope this helps you

Comment: No, I am trying to achieve the above mentioned design.